# odoo: How to only show logged in users the website

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I use odoo as a system in our company and want to use the website for internal news and informations. However the public should not see the website - only logged in users should! Viewers who aren't logged in should be redirected to the login screen.

Is that possible and how could I do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple , just give **auth="user"** in your method at main.py file in controller.

```
@http.route('/name', type='http', csrf=False, auth='user', website=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you define the route with @http.route you have a parameter "auth", where you define that. From the odoo documentation:

```
auth –

The type of authentication method, can on of the following:

    user: The user must be authenticated and the current request will perform using the rights of the user.
    public: The user may or may not be authenticated. If she isn’t, the current request will perform using the shared Public user.
    none: The method is always active, even if there is no database. Mainly used by the framework and authentication modules. There request code will not have any facilities to access the database nor have any configuration indicating the current database nor the current user.
```

Have a look to https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/http.html

Comment: That seems like a great solution. Where can I edit these Web Controllers now to add the needed code with all the routing? Can you give me some more informations?

Comment: It is like developing a website with Odoo, you have a short intro at: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/website.html